# Split a large video file into small clips 15 seconds each

Tags: video, ffmpeg, split

How do I split a large mp4 file using `ffmpeg`, into smaller clips, which are 15 seconds each?

Comment: what video player are you using to play the files?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 15 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart out%03d.mp4
```

- This example will use [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode, so re-encoding will be avoided. However, it has to cut on the nearest keyframes so accuracy is not guaranteed. Remove `-c copy` if you need more accuracy, but note that re-encoding will occur.
- Output files in this example will be named `out001.mp4`, `out002.mp4`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, and if the video file is located in the Ubuntu desktop, how do I include the path in the command? )Let's assume the output files are created in the desktop). Kindly let me know

Comment: @DominicIsaiah I updated the example to include the Desktop in the path to the input. See [Ubuntu Wiki: Using the Terminal - File & Directory Commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands) for more info.

Comment: Some of the clips would play, but others would show error messages or would not play at all. I feel some of the clips got corrupted. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @DominicIsaiah Please provide a pastebin link showing your command and the complete console output. What player did you use? Can you provide the input file?

Comment: I used the same command which you mentioned "ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/in.mp4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 15 \
-segment_format_options movflags=+faststart out%03d.mp4"